# How to resolve 'unexpected number' exception during 'ng serve'

Tags: angular

I had an angular project in my local mac machine and was working fine after 'ng serve'. I recently migrated it into a windows 10 machine and after 'ng serve' I am getting 'Unhandled exception: Unexpected number' as in

`

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected number
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1070:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1120:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1176:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1000:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:899:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1042:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:77:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (F:\LIMITED\chambuya\scratchpad\learn_angular\test-scss-with\node_modules\parse5\lib\tokenizer\index.js:5:14)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1156:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1176:10)`

Current machine specs [Windows 10]:
```

`

```
Angular CLI: 8.3.25
Node: 12.16.2
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 8.2.14
```

`Prevouse Machine Specs:`

```
Angular CLI: 8.3.1
Node: 12.14.2
OS: darwin x64
Angular: 8.2.14
```

`
How do I go about to resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried removing node_modules and `npm install` after migrating? Seems like an external module binary issue for me at first sight.